# Why doesn't suspend work when ThinkPad T500 laptop lid is closed when it is working from the command line or from clicking on the GUI?

Tags: 12.10, suspend, thinkpad

I'm running Ubuntu 12.10 on my ThinkPad T500 with an extra monitor.

```
$ uname -a
Linux emre-laptop 3.5.0-25-generic #38-Ubuntu SMP Mon Feb 18 23:28:26 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

The `pm-suspend` command works perfectly from the command line, <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> (usual sleep key combination) works fine, and clicking 'Suspend' from the GUI works without any problems:

[image: Suspend works fine when invoked from GUI]

I have also checked my settings, they seem to be fine:

[image: Suspend settings]

But the suspend functionality doesn't work when the laptop is closed. When I close the lid the external monitor goes blank, but the laptop does not go into sleep mode. When I open the lid I have a blank screen both on the laptop and the external monitor.

I have tried the workaround given at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-power-manager/+bug/863834 and created a file:

```
$ ls -l /etc/acpi/local/lid.post.sh 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 696 Feb 26 20:31 /etc/acpi/local/lid.post.sh
```

The contents of the file:

```
#!/bin/bash
grep -q closed /proc/acpi/button/lid/*/state
if [ $? = 0 ]
then
/usr/sbin/pm-suspend
fi
```

Any suggestions or workarounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, apparently one needs to be more careful with filenames! In my case, I have inadvertently created the wrong file: /etc/acpi/local/lid.post.sh whereas the correct filename should have been:

```
/etc/acpi/local/lid.sh.post
```

as was described correctly in the workaround. Renaming the file correctly solved the suspending problem.